# Translate or convert French accented characters to base ASCII characters

Tags: character-encoding, db2

We have a `Customer` table with the "First name" and "Last name" columns. There are million of records in the table. Few of the records have **French Accented** charaters.

Example: Adélaïde, Amélie , etc.

I am looking for a DB2 function that can convert or translate accents into base ASCII characters.

**Example:**

**Input:** Amélie

**Output:** Amelia

I know we have a solution in Java. We can use Apache Commons `StringUtils` library to convert.

```
String input = StringUtils.stripAccents("Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ");
System.out.println(input);
```

As of release 3.4, this does not work for Ø or Ł.

**Below solution works and covers all the characters.**
    translate(col,'aAeEiIoOuUaAeEuUaAeEiIoOuUeEiIoOuUcCnNaaaiAAAIoOyydDYooOOA','áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚàÀèÈùÙâÂêÊîÎôÔûÛëËïÏöÖüÜçÇñÑäãåìÄÃÅÌøØÿýðÐÝòõÒÕæ')

Note: æ is converted to A

Comment: Do you consider also, say, devanagari or arabic somehow _not normal_?

Comment: For the record there is a Db2 LUW example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100215/remove-accents-db2/52304253#52304253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the translate function if you want :

```
  translate(upper(ColName),'AAAEEEIIIOOOUUU','ÁÀÄÉÈËÍÌÏÓÒÖÚÙÜ')
```

Comment: using below command covers all the characters....translate(colname,'aAeEiIoOuUaAeEuUaAeEiIoOuUeEiIoOuUcCnNaaaiAAAIoOyydDYooOOA','áÁéÉíÍóÓúÚàÀèÈùÙâÂêÊîÎôÔûÛëËïÏöÖüÜçÇñÑäãåìÄÃÅÌøØÿýðÐÝòõÒÕæ')

Answer (score 0):

https://www.senat.fr/questions/base/2018/qSEQ180303860.html

states the only characters authorized for french citizens names are

à-â-ä-é-è-ê-ë-ï-î-ô-ö-ù-û-ü-ÿ-ç and æ and œ so the answer would be

```
replace(replace((translate(lower(ColName),'aaaeeeeiioouuuyc','àâäéèêëïîôöùûüÿç')),'æ','ae'),'œ','oe')
```